# AWS ECS Task Error - Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ecs-XXX

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I'm new to Docker but know a little bit of AWS. I currently have a Docker image that's working perfectly on local host. I've packaged up my Docker image to ECR and copied the URI and used the URI in the cluster on ECS. I've created a task on the cluster but when I try to run the task, I get this error

> STOPPED (CannotStartContainerError: Error response from dae)

Expanding the error further provides the error details as:

> CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ecs-XXXX-New-1-XXXXX-new-c0f1889582c3fea77500

If I SSH into the EC2 instance I can't pull the docker image, I get this error:

> no basic auth credentials

I've checked all permissions in IAM and everything is as it should be and the answers I come across don't mention AWS.

I'm so stuck right now!

Thanks in advance